# Is there any difference in template declaration keyword

Tags: c++

Is there any difference or rule why or when to use which

`template <class T>` or `template <typename T>`

Is there preferred option which to use?
I see that they are used interchangeably and compiler doesn't complain about it.

Comment: There's no difference.

Comment: `class T` among template parameters may be a forward declaration, not a template parameter, potentially leading to confusion. No idea why would they reuse `class` keyword here for unrelated purpose.

Comment: Aside:  if I remember correctly (and maybe I don't), here's one spot where `class` and `struct` are not interchangeable — can't do `template <struct T>`.

Comment: There's no difference since C++17